# Ball Breaker Game - Ball is getting stuck to paddle after certain bounces - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created a block breaker game using Unity. Everything works fine except sometimes, the ball gets stuck to the paddle and then gets released after bit of time, causing it's speed to decrease. Please help as I am on the verge of completing my project :)

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Paddle paddle;
    private Vector3 paddleToBallVector;
    private bool hasStarted = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        paddle = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Paddle>();
        paddleToBallVector = this.transform.position - paddle.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!hasStarted)
        {
            //Lock the ball relative to paddle..
            this.transform.position = paddle.transform.position + paddleToBallVector;
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                print("Mouse Clicked, Ball Launched!!");
                hasStarted = true;
                this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(2f, 10f);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c)
    {
        Vector2 tweak = new Vector2(Random.Range(0f,0.2f),Random.Range(0,0.2f));
        if (hasStarted)
        {
            //    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            Rigidbody2D rigidbody = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rigidbody.velocity += tweak;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S. - Attached code is only for the ball object.

Comment: Hard to say, but make sure to use a frictionless physic material, and continuous collision detection mode.

Comment: How fast is your ball going? could the `tweak` be negating it's velocity entierly?

Comment: @Iggy I have already set the friction to the 0. So i don't think that could be the issue.

Comment: @Jake actually I have added the tweak because ball was getting into the endless up-down loop and after adding the tweak, the ball just works fine. but now I got this issue of paddle and ball cuddling each other sometimes ;)

Comment: @Jake actually my bal goes up to the top of the window once got hit or launched!!!

Comment: @Iggy Thank you. I have changed the collision detection mode to continuous from discrete and now it works fine. Thanks a lot, pal. :)